# Create single cell list from another cell containing a text string

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

is there a way to build a list in a single cell from a sting in another cell and without impacting the x400 line.

I've tried the following with no joy

```
=CONCATENATE(A19&CHAR(10), ";")
=TEXTJOIN( "; "&CHAR(10),TRUE,A19)
=TEXTJOIN({"; "}, TRUE, A11&CHAR(10))
```

| Input String | Desired Output List In Single Cell |
| --- | --- |
| smtp:postmaster@test.com;smtp:user1@onetest.co.uk;smtp:user1@testing.com;SMTP:user1@thetest.com;smtp:user1@test.local;X400:C=GB;A= ;P=Test;O=Exchange;S=User;G=1; | smtp:postmaster@test.com; smtp:user1@onetest.co.uk; smtp:user1@testing.com; SMTP:user1@thetest.com; smtp:user1@test.local; X400:C=GB;A=;P=Test;O=Exchange;S=User;G=1; |

Comment: it is unclear what you are trying to do.  Please include the expected output.

Comment: Under the cell header 'Input String' is a string. I would like to present that string as a list in the adjacent cell. Example can be found under the cell header 'Desired Output List In Single Cell'. (the table above, scroll right, to see). Thankyou.

Comment: Is it fair to say that you'd like to replace all those semicolons only after an email address and leave the rest untouched? Btw, you mentioned Excel 2010 in your tags yet use TEXTJOIN?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parse the string and use SUBSTITUTE:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(LEFT(A1,SEARCH("x400",A1)-1),";",";"&CHAR(10))&MID(A1,SEARCH("x400",A1),LEN(A1))
```

[image]

Comment: Boom. Thank you Scott Craner