# Create Single Cell Lists from Text Strings With ';' Semi-Colon Delimiter

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I would like to build a list within a single cell from a sting stored another cell. The string has a semi colon delimiter ';' to separate the string SMTP, smtp, X400, FAX. Unfortunately the x400 portion of the string also has semi colons which need to be kept. Its delimiter is a second semi colon ';;'.

I need some help expanding this answer from yesterday, which provides an example of the output i need - https://stackoverflow.com/a/69948563/14638694; as does the picture.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w4GH2.png)

| Input Cell | Output Cell |
| --- | --- |
| SMTP:userS1@thetest.com;X400:C=GB;A= ;P=TEST;O=Exchange;S=S1;G=user;I=P;;smtp:user1@test.local;FAX:User P. S1[userS1]@test.local | List From Input Cell |
| X400:C=GB;A= ;P=TEST;O=Exchange;S=41;G=user; | X400:C=GB;A= ;P=TEST;O=Exchange;S=41;G=user\ |
| SMTP:user2@thetest.com;X400:C=GB;A= ;P=TEST;O=Exchange;S=2;G=user;;smtp:user2@test.local;FAX:user 2[user2]@test.local | List From Input Cell |
| X400:C=GB;A= ;P=TEST;O=Exchange;S=17;G=user;;FAX:user 17[user17]@test.local | List From Input Cell |
| SMTP:user3@thetest.com;X400:C=GB;A= ;P=TEST;O=Exchange;S=3;G=user;;smtp:user3@test.local;FAX:user 3[user3]@test.local | List From Input Cell |
| X400:C=GB;A= ;P=TEST;O=Exchange;S=4;G=user;;smtp:user4@test.local | List From Input Cell |
| FAX:user 6[user6]@test.local;X400:C=GB;A= ;P=TEST;O=Exchange;S=6;G=user; | List From Input Cell |
| smtp:user5@test.local | List From Input Cell |

Comment: Welcome to SO. I've provided a solution below. However, you should avoid treating SO like a free coding service. That means you should make an effort to solve the problem yourself, show what you've done, and explain why that isn't doing what you want. And pointing to another answer you've received, doesn't constitute making an effort. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution would be to use nested SUBSTITUTE functions per:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,";SMTP",CHAR(10)&"SMTP"),";smtp",CHAR(10)&"smtp"),";X400",CHAR(10)&"X400"),";FAX",CHAR(10)&"FAX")
```

Notes:

1. The above would be as for an input cell at A1
2. It replaces any semicolon delimiter, that appears before any the defined protocol ID's with a linefeed [i.e. Char(10)]
3. SUBSTITUTE is case sensitive (hence the need for both SMTP and smtp)

   - If there's other cases of that (e.g. X400 and x400), you need to nest in another SUBSTITUTE to cater for those
4. If (as the examples suggest) SMTP will appear first or not at all, you could remove substitution of that protocol ID

Comment: Are you sure you want the output in one cell? (What's the benefit to the output in one cell compared to the input?). What are you planning to use the data for after your output?